# SQL Server 2000 - Picking one row out of many based on cell value

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-order-by, case

I've got an interesting dilemma that has stumped me and a coworker. I'm trying to construct a sql query that will allow me to pull phone extensions for an employee to be published on a public website. In our phone system (SQL Server 2000 based) a user can have up to three extensions (so far): a 3XXX number (direct line), a 5XXX (boss groups, for a person with a secretary and multi-line phones) and a 7XXX (voicemail).

Most people have either a 3XXX or 7XXX extension. Only a few have the 5XXX, but we also have people who, via promotions, have gained additional numbers. For example, a teacher (who only gets a voicemail/7XXX) was promoted to Assistance Principal and gets a direct line/3XXX and then become a Director and gets a secretary, thus a 5XXX.

We want to publish these numbers in the order of 5XXX then 3XXX then 7XXX, so most of the direct routes using ORDER BY are out the window. I've gotten the query to the point where it will return something like this:

```
UserID | Extension |Employee ID 
-------------------------------
USER 1 | 3234      |1234
USER 1 | 5235      |1234
USER 1 | 7364      |1234
```

I cannot, however, rely on the order that they may be in, due to when their extension was added to the system. I also have no control over removing the other extensions.

We tried doing some case statements but ran into nothing very good. Below is the SQL we are using which is becoming very complicated and is way over my head. Can anyone shine some light on how we can intelligently get one value into each row that would return the employee ID and phone extension based on the rules from above? The firstname, lastname stuff is just for checking and not part of the final.

Sorry if this sound like a lot, just getting desperate over here.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
FirstName, LastName, PrimaryFaxNumber, MAX(CASE WHEN Expr1 IS NOT NULL THEN Expr1 ELSE CASE WHEN Expr2 IS NOT NULL 
                      THEN Expr2 ELSE Expr3 END END) AS Extension
FROM         (SELECT     sub.FirstName, sub.LastName, sub.PrimaryFaxNumber, da.DtmfAccessId, CASE WHEN LEFT(CAST(da.DtmfAccessId AS nvarchar), 1) 
                                              = '5' THEN da.DtmfAccessId END AS Expr1, CASE WHEN LEFT(CAST(da.DtmfAccessId AS nvarchar), 1) 
                                              = '3' THEN da.DtmfAccessId END AS Expr2, CASE WHEN LEFT(CAST(da.DtmfAccessId AS nvarchar), 1) 
                                              = '7' THEN da.DtmfAccessId END AS Expr3
                       FROM          Subscriber sub FULL OUTER JOIN
                                              DtmfAccessId da ON da.ParentObjectId = sub.SubscriberObjectId
                       WHERE      (sub.SubscriberObjectId IS NOT NULL) AND (sub.PrimaryFaxNumber IS NOT NULL) AND (CAST(da.DtmfAccessId AS BIGINT) < 9999)) 
                      DERIVEDTBL
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, PrimaryFaxNumber
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a select of all 5xxx UNION 3xx but not 5xxx union 7xxx but not 5xxx or 3xxx.

Actual query will look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID, Extension 
    FROM AccessId 
        WHERE LEFT(CAST(Extension AS nvarchar), 1)='5' 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID, Extension 
    FROM AccessId 
        WHERE LEFT(CAST(Extension AS nvarchar), 1)='3' 
            AND NOT EXIST (
                SELECT EmployeeID FROM AccessId 
                    WHERE LEFT(CAST(Extension AS nvarchar), 1)='5')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID, Extension 
    FROM AccessId 
            WHERE LEFT(CAST(Extension AS nvarchar), 1)='7' 
                AND NOT EXIST (
                    SELECT EmployeeID FROM AccessId 
                        WHERE LEFT(CAST(Extension AS nvarchar), 1)='3' 
                            OR LEFT(CAST(Extension AS nvarchar), 1)='5');
```

There might exist faster solutions though.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, this was exactly what I needed (with some modifications).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, all you need is to sort your result by `LEFT(extension,1)`, so you will have

```
SELECT * FROM (your_your_query)a
ORDER BY a.user_id, CASE LEFT(a.extension,1)
WHEN '5' THEN 1
WHEN '3' THEN 2
WHEN '7' THEN 3
ELSE 4
END
```